# Standalone library for AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, open-source

I have been using the fantastic jQuery library for quite some time and have become familar with its AJAX capabilities. I am working on a project which only requires the AJAX capabilities of jQuery. Separating this logic from jQuery is not so easy because there are so many dependencies.

I need an AJAX library which can achieve the following (in the same way that jQuery allows):

- Load script from another domain
- Load script from same domain
- Execute callback as soon as script has been executed

Using jQuery this can be achieved easily using:

```
$.ajax({
    type     : 'GET',
    url      : url,
    dataType : 'script',
    cache    : true,

    success: function() {
       // script has literally just finished executing...
    }
})
```

Which well established (and lightweight) open source library would achieve these requirements?

Comment: What dependencies does jQuery have that are causing problems? If it's just the size of jQuery that is unacceptable, then you might want to look at [jx](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jx/). Then again, minified jQuery is only 31K...

Comment: @voithos jQuery ajax requires at least (according to jQuery forum) 7 scripts in order to function because it makes use of its own functionality. 31K is small, but it still seems wasteful when the only requirement is AJAX. I will take a look into "jx". Do you know whether it supports an equivalent of the "script" dataType jQuery option? cheers

Comment: It sounds like you're optimizing without needing to. 31K is tiny. If you don't have a proven need to use something smaller, I would recommend using what you know - your time is more valuable than ~20K saved in script transfers. Besides, you may end up using jQuery in unforeseen ways... Unless, of course, you just want to learn a different library; that's OK.

Comment: @voithos I can understand what you are saying. If possible I wanted to avoid the need to use a large and complex library like jQuery. I'll have a play with "jx" and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Well part of the complexity is due to needing selectors, on click handlers etc etc... That being said, if you want a lighter weight library try dojo. Dojo let's you add whatever components you like to your build and lets you make it as heavy or as light as you'd like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turns out that the functionality that I require is not truly part of an AJAX response. Looking in the jQuery source I found that the "script" handler is essentially creating a "script" element temporarily and then removing it once it has loaded.

Link to relevant jQuery source:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js

The following page describes this process in greater detail:
http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/109